# In 8086 I want to print the inputed binary and print it as it is

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I have done this so far, but at printing it only shows high bit digits. 
How to solve that issue? I have tried everything in my knowledge.

I want output like this:

> input: 101
>   output: 101
>
> 1 (number of 0 )
>
> 2 (number of 1)

but I am getting output like this:

> input:101
>
> output: 000
>
> 3
>
> 0

What is the issue and how to solve it?
Please help me solve this issue.

```
 .MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA

D DB 0
F DB 0
C DB 0

.CODE  
MAIN PROC  
MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX


XOR BX,BX
MOV AH,1
INT 21H



WHILE_:


CMP AL,0DH
JE NEW_LINE
AND AL,0FH
SHL BX,1
OR BL,AL
INT 21H
INC C
JMP WHILE_




NEW_LINE:  

MOV AH,2
MOV DL,0AH
INT 21H
MOV DL,0DH
INT 21H

MOV CL,1
MOV CH,0



PRINT:

CMP CH,C
JE END_
INC CH
SHL BX,CL
JC RS


MOV AH,2
MOV DL,30H
INC D
INT 21H
JMP PRINT



RS:
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,31H
INC F
INT 21H
JMP PRINT



END_:
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,0AH
INT 21H
MOV DL,0DH
INT 21H


MOV AH,2
ADD D,30H
MOV DL,D
INT 21H 

MOV AH,2
MOV DL,0AH
INT 21H
MOV DL,0DH
INT 21H

MOV AH,2
ADD F,30H
MOV DL,F
INT 21H

MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H


  MAIN ENDP
    END MAIN
```

Comment: I honestly cannot figure out what you are saying.

Comment: How do you expect `SHL BX,CL` to generate a carry in the scenario you described (where the input is `101`)? Perhaps you meant to do `SHR BX,1`, though you'll be printing the bits in reverse order then.

Comment: I don't understand why you are not using an interrupt function that first reads a string input and then examines each character in a loop. Your code lacks **any comments at all**, and it is unclear where you are keeping the counts - there are only the three storage bytes `D` and `F` and `C` and how confusing are those names anyway? Registers, hex, or what?

Answer (score 1):

### On the input side:

Each digit in the inputted number should provide a single bit in `BX`. To get to this, you need to mask using `and al, 1` instead of the `and al, 0Fh` that you wrote.

```
WHILE_:
 CMP AL, 13
 JE  NEW_LINE
 AND AL, 1        ;This has changed!
 SHL BX, 1        ;Makes room to receive a single bit
 OR  BL, AL       ;Adds the bit
 INT 21h
 INC C            ;Counts the inputted bits
 JMP WHILE_
```

### On the output side:

Since the input in now in the **lowest bits** of `BX`, you need to first move those bits to the **high end** of the same register `BX`.
Given that `BX` has 16 bit positions and that the number of bits that were inputted is in the *C* variable, you can write:

```
 mov cl, 16       ;Total bits in BX
 sub cl, C        ; minus count of inputted bits
 shl bx, cl       ;Now inputted bits start at bit[15]

 MOV CH, 0
PRINT:
 CMP CH, C
 JE  END_
 INC CH
 SHL BX, 1        ;Here you shift out the highest bit
 JC  RS
 ; and so on...
```